# Sonar and PHPMD: how to exclude directories

Tags: php, static, sonarqube, analysis, phpmd

I'm trying Sonar and i've got some issues with it for a php project.

I have to do it multi-module to get at least php and js analysis.

this is my sonar-project.properties:

sonar.projectKey=xxxx
sonar.projectName=xxxx
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

```
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=
sonar.language=php
sonar.exclusions=htdocs/libraries/externals/**
sonar.phpCodesniffer.skip=true

sonar.modules=php-module,js-module

# PHP module
php-module.sonar.projectName=PHP Module
php-module.sonar.language=php
php-module.sonar.sources=
php-module.sonar.projectBaseDir=htdocs
php-module.sonar.exclusions=libraries/externals/**

# JavaScript module
js-module.sonar.projectName=JavaScript Module
js-module.sonar.language=js
js-module.sonar.sources=js
js-module.sonar.projectBaseDir=htdocs
```

But when i run sonar-runner, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: PHPMD execution failed with returned code '1'. Please check the documentation of PHPMD to know more about this failure
```

and the PHPMD error is

```
 The parser has reached an invalid state near line "32" in file "/var/www/vhosts/dev3.xxxx.local/htdocs/libraries/externals/AvaTax4PHP/classes/ATConfig.class.php". Please check the following conditions: The keyword "parent" was used as type hint but the class "ATConfig" does not declare a parent.
```

**But why is that happening if i've excluded the dir libraries in the project and the module?**

Do i have to specify to PHPMD another list of exclusions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PHPMD (just as for PHP CodeSniffer, for example) you will have to specify a separate exclude pattern. You can use PHPMD's `--exclude`parameter for that.

Took me a while to figure it out, but you can set PHPMD's command line parameters with the following setting in your `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.phpPmd.argumentLine=--exclude libraries/externals
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this FAQ entry to know how to achieve your goal: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin+FAQ#PHPPluginFAQ-HowdoIpreventexternaltoolsfromanalyzingsomesourcefiles

BTW, you should declare:

```
php-module.sonar.sources=.
```

, instead of:

```
php-module.sonar.sources=
```